# WebDAV - cannot mount/access webshare

Tags: webdav, iis-8.5

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. I created a website (on port 80), with physical location on an azure file share \\xyz.file.core.windows.net\share. I also created a local account with same user and pass as the one for azure file share so I can access it.

In IIS Authentication i have both Anonymus and ASP Impersonation enabled.
In WebDAV Authoring Rules I have allowed access to a few users, U1, U2.

If I try to go to http://1.1.1.1, i get prompted for user and pass, but credentials are not accepted. I tried net use and I get:

> System error 1244 has occurred.
>
> The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated.

If I change the WebDAV Authoring Rule to allow All Users, I can connect with no problem, so there's something wrong with the way i try to authenticate maybe ?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more on IIS authentication for WebDAV i found that it needs I needed to enable Windows Authentication for my website and also add an Authorization Rule for the users I want to have access to this share. Everything else remained the same regarding WebDAV Authoring Rules.